# Fun with GAE: using key_name as PK?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to insert new entities programatically as well as manually. For this I was thinking about using key_name to uniquely identify an entity.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the model to generate a new unique key name when I create the entity.

On the other hand, I cannot create the ID (which is unique across data store) manually.

How can I do "create unique key name if provided value is None"?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need a string id (as opposed to an automatically assigned integer id), you could use a random string generator, or unique id generator like [uuid.uuid4](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4).

Comment: No I don't need a string id! But the Key Name property is of type string and I don't think I can change that. Or can I?

Comment: I really just need a unique identifier that I can edit manually and programatically.

Comment: You can't change entity keys once they are created. But you can create an entity without a key name and then still have a unique id (an integer one) with: e = Entity() / e.put() / id_or_name = e.key().id_or_name()

Comment: So there is no way to have a unique identifier (unique across just one entity is good enough) that will be generated automatically if I leave it blank and will be set to the value I provide if I provide it?

Comment: @Matt What does "unique across one entity" mean? Every ID is unique across one entity, even if you use '1' for all of them. If you don't supply a key name, an ID will be generated that's unique across the kind and parent, though. Every entity either has an ID or a name, not both.

Comment: But if I create it using `e = Entity(key_name='somestring') e.put()` then it will have both, a 'Key Name' *and* an 'ID'. So I'm not sure what you mean with your last sentence.

Comment: We have a terminology problem here. "key name" is not a model property, it is an attribute of entity keys. Keys have a ID -- which can be an integer or string ID (also called "id" and "name", respectively, by the Model/Key classes). If you don't define an ID in the entity key an integer one is automatically assigned after the entity is saved.

Comment: @Matt No, it won't. If you specify a key name, no auto-numbered ID will be generated. Every entity has exactly one of the two. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question. If you want an automatically-generated key name, just leave out the key when you instantiate the object - one will be automatically assigned when you call `put()`.

Comment: No it will be set to None I tried that. So for example if I do `e = Entity() e.put()` then this will have 'None' in the column 'Key Name'.

Comment: Yes, key name will be none. But so what? It still has a unique ID.

Comment: Yes, but if I want to specify ID manually I can't. Because I cannot guarantee uniqueness across the entire data store if I pick my own ID. On the other hand, it's easy to ensure uniqueness across just one entity. This is why I want to use Key Name as PK.

Comment: @Matt You're still confusing us. You say you want to be able to choose your own ID, but in your question you say you don't know how to pick one. Do you want IDs generated for you, or don't you?

Comment: Both: I want it to be generated if I leave it blank but if I provide it I want it to be what I provide.

Comment: @Matt Then leave it blank for an auto-generated ID, and fill it in for a string key. You can get whichever exists with `entity.key.id_or_name()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to `get`, I want to `set`. As I understand it I cannot set 'ID'.

Comment: Why do you _want_ to set the ID? You've already said you don't know what to set it to.

Answer (score 1):

If most of the time you want your entities to have automatically assigned ids, then just go around creating your entities (without passing a `key` or `key_name`), the key will be auto-assigned and your entities will have `.key().id()` available.

If sometimes you need to assign the numeric ids manually, then you can [reserve a block](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html) of ids so that AppEngine will never auto-assign them, and then you can use an `id` from this reserved range whenever you want to assign an id to a known entity. To assign an id to an entity you create a `Key` for that entity:

```
# reserve ids 4000 to 5000 for use manually on the Customer entity
db.allocate_id_range(db.Key.from_path('Customer',1),4000,5000)

# manualy create a customer with id 4501
bob = Customer(key=db.Key.from_path('Customer',4501), name='bob')
bob.put()
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! I'm glad someone understands my question.